# How to solve a nonhomo quasilinear avection equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

So I need to solve this equation:

$$ u_t + uu_x = -ku^2, k, t > 0, u(x, 0) = 1, x \in \mathbb{R}$$

While using characteristics doesn't really work - that if I try

$$ \dfrac{dt}{1} = \dfrac{dx}{u} = \dfrac{du}{-ku^2}, $$

then I only get $u = \dfrac{1}{kt + 1}$. But doesn't $u$ also depend on $x$? Should I use other methods to find the solution? Then, how to sketch the characteristics for this equation? Constant lines of $t$?

Comment: No, the solution does not not have to depend on $x$. You can check that your solution satisfies the PDE and the initial condition and, assuming the solution to the problem is unique, then what you have found _is_ the solution to the problem.

Comment: Well that constant initial condition is what I have. Anyway, how to sketch the characteristics for this equation? Constant lines of $t$?

Answer (score 1):

The solution $$u(x,t) = \frac{1}{kt+1}$$
valid for all times $t> -1/k$
is correct. Indeed, the initial condition $u(x,0)=1$ is satisfied, and the PDE $u_t + uu_x = -ku^2$ is satisfied too. To plot the characteristics, note that $dx/dt = u$. Thus, the characteristics are curves of the form
$$
x(t) = x_0 + \frac1{k}\ln (kt + 1)
$$
where $x_0$ is a constant such that $x(0) = x_0$.